# Dataframe: how to lookup values in another table, if not found, return blank/Databricks, pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I'm working in Databricks to create data frame based on two existing tables. I need to look up values in 2nd table, return the value, if not found, then return blank.
for example:
df1:
| Material | KG       |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 10       |
| 2        | 50       |
| 3        | 100      |
| 4        | 80       |
| 5        | 60       |

df2:

| Material | Conversion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 12 |

I'd like to have the below df3

| Material | KG | Conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 50 |  |
| 3 | 100 | 5 |
| 4 | 80 |  |
| 5 | 60 | 12 |

I used the below to add, but it join only those found in df2, so it only shows material 135 and removed Material 24, I still want to keep 1-5
df3 = df1.join(df2,["Material"]).withColumnRenamed("Material", "Material_new").drop("Material_new")
display(df3)

I'd like to have the below df3

| Material | KG | Conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 50 |  |
| 3 | 100 | 5 |
| 4 | 80 |  |
| 5 | 60 | 12 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`left`** join for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,10),(2,50),(3,100),(4,80),(5,60)],['Material','KG'])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1.5),(3,5.0),(5,12.0)],['Material','Conversion'])
df.join(df1,['Material'],'left').show(10,False)
#+--------+---+----------+
#|Material|KG |Conversion|
#+--------+---+----------+
#|1       |10 |1.5       |
#|2       |50 |null      |
#|3       |100|5.0       |
#|4       |80 |null      |
#|5       |60 |12.0      |
#+--------+---+----------+
```

---

Replace `null` with `' '`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,10),(2,50),(3,100),(4,80),(5,60)],['Material','KG'])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1.5),(3,5.0),(5,12.0)],['Material','Conversion'])
df.join(df1,['Material'],'left').\
  withColumn("conversion",when(col("conversion").isNull(),lit(" ")).\
    otherwise(col("conversion"))).\
      show(10,False)
#+--------+---+----------+
#|Material|KG |conversion|
#+--------+---+----------+
#|1       |10 |1.5       |
#|2       |50 |          |
#|3       |100|5.0       |
#|4       |80 |          |
#|5       |60 |12.0      |
#+--------+---+----------+
```